# Google is appending branded url to title in search results with undesired capitalization

Tags: google-search, search-results, meta-tags, title

I work for an organization with a website domain that is two words that are placed together.  For branding reasons, we always display the url as `Loremipsum.com` or `loremipsum.com` and NEVER `LoremIpsum.com` (referred to as camel-case).  Recently, it appears that in Google search result pages the domain name with the unwanted capital letter is getting appended to the page title like:

> This is My Awesome Page Title - LoremIpsum.com

when we would prefer it to be:

> This is My Awesome Page Title - loremipsum.com

I have scoured the source code of the site and nowhere do I see the domain displayed this way.  It certainly isn't in any `<title>` or `<h1>` tags.  It is as if Google determined that this how the domain name should be displayed.

I've looked in Webmaster Tools and Analytics to see if the site was ever claimed using camel case but can't find anything.

Comment: It has been doing this for a month or so. It hit my site and even puts a [ in front of the .org. Annoying. I do not mind the branding so much, but Google already limits the title to 55 characters. This is not a problem with your site. It is a bit of silliness on Google's part. Though I am not sure why.

Comment: I just took a quick look. If you fill up nearly all of the 55 characters that Google uses for the SERP link, they will not append your domain name. That and a dollar will buy you a cup of coffee, but not at Starbucks.

Comment: @Anonymous2781eb Is your brand ever spelled with two capitalized words, or commonly used with capitals? If so, seems they derived the case from either your content, or as a keyword or brand commonly spelled with upper case. Shouldn't be a problem since the domain portion of a URL is [case-insensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax).

Comment: As dan suggests, I think that Google simply sees the two words and is trying to be "helpful" to users. Unfortunately I don't think there is much you can do about this!? Unless you perhaps _change_ the title, as closetnoc suggests, but then there is no guarantee what title Google will use in the SERPs.

Comment: I am sure that Google is seeing your domain name as two dictionary terms and using mixed case to highlight the dictionary terms. w3d is right that Google may or may not use your title, however, if your titles are unique from page to page, are not too short or too long, differs from description meta-tag and h1 tag, as well as appear to be sentences and/or conversational, I will bet even money that Google will use the title tag that you provided.

Comment: Using camel case in domain names can be quite helpful.  There is a huge difference between ExpertsExchange and ExpertSexChange.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the site uses Loremipsum.com as the name of site. But Google knows that Lorem and Ipsum are two separate words and then to clarify things for searchers it transforms the sitename to camel-case.

The reason why Google attempts to fix your title is that Google doesn't think your titles are good enough. Maybe they aren't unique or they doesn't seem to match the page content.

I have a site which uses the index page title *(Company name | Keyword, keyword and keyword in City)* on all pages. Let me show some examples of what Google choosed for building the search results titles:

1. [filename] - [title]
2. [filename] - [company name] *(Note: company name is included in the title)*
3. [title]
4. [h1] - [title]
5. [link text from another page *(Read more...)*] - [title]
6. [important single word used in both filename and h1] - [title]
7. [h2] - [title] *(Note: The page had a h1 and several h2)*

If you want your self-written title to appear in search results: rewrite it until it does.